# Update long process' progress via callback instead of polling

Tags: python, python-3.x

in my Python script I am triggering a long process (drive()) that is encapsulated into a class method:

car.py

```py
import time


class Car(object):

    def __init__(self, sleep_time_in_seconds, miles_to_drive):
        self.sleep_time_in_seconds = sleep_time_in_seconds
        self.miles_to_drive = miles_to_drive

    def drive(self):

        for mile in range(self.miles_to_drive):
            print('driving mile #{}'.format(mile))
            time.sleep(self.sleep_time_in_seconds)
```

app.py

```py
from car import Car

sleep_time = 2
total_miles = 5

car = Car(sleep_time_in_seconds=sleep_time, miles_to_drive=total_miles)
car.drive()


def print_driven_distance_in_percent(driven_miles):
    print("Driven distance: {}%".format(100 * driven_miles / total_miles))
```

In the main script `app.py` I'd like to know the progress of the `drive()` process. One way of solving this would be to create a loop that polls the current progress from the `Car` class. If the `Car` class would inherit from Thread - polling seems to be an expected pattern as far as I have googled... 
I'm just curious whether it's possible to somehow notify the main script from within the `Car` class about the current progress. 
I thought about maybe creating a wrapper class that I can pass as argument to the `Car` class, and the car instance then can call the wrapper class' print_progress function. 
Or is there a more pythonic way to notify the caller script on demand?

Thanks

EDIT:

Based on Artiom Kozyrev's answer - this is what I wanted to achieve:

```py
import time
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue


def ask_queue(q):
    """
    The function to control status of our status display thread
    q - Queue - need to show status of task
    """
    while True:
        x = q.get()  # take element from Queue
        if x == "STOP":
            break
        print("Process completed in {} percents".format(x))
    print("100% finished")


class MyClass:
    """My example class"""
    def __init__(self, name, status_queue):
        self.name = name
        self.status_queue = status_queue

    def my_run(self):
        """
        The function we would like to monitor
        """
        # th = Thread(target=MyClass.ask_queue, args=(self.status_queue,), )  # monitoring thread
        # th.start()  # start monitoring thread
        for i in range(100):  # start doing our main function we would like to monitor
            print("{} {}".format(self.name, i))
            if i % 5 == 0:  # every 5 steps show status of progress
                self.status_queue.put(i)  # send status to Queue
                time.sleep(0.1)
        self.status_queue.put("STOP")  # stop Queue
        # th.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    q = Queue()

    th = Thread(target=ask_queue, args=(q,), )  # monitoring thread
    th.start()  # start monitoring thread

    # tests
    x = MyClass("Maria", q)
    x.my_run()

    th.join()
```

Thanks to all!!

Comment: Replace `mile` with `self.mile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for interesting question, typically you do not need to use status as a separate thread for the case, you can just print status in the method you would like to monitor, but for training purpose you solve the issue the follwoing way, please follow comments and feel free to ask:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue


class MyClass:
    """My example class"""
    def __init__(self, name, status_queue):
        self.name = name
        self.status_queue = status_queue

    @staticmethod
    def ask_queue(q):
        """
        The function to control status of our status display thread
        q - Queue - need to show status of task
        """
        while True:
            x = q.get()  # take element from Queue
            if x == "STOP":
                break
            print("Process completed in {} percents".format(x))
        print("100% finished")

    def my_run(self):
        """
        The function we would like to monitor
        """
        th = Thread(target=MyClass.ask_queue, args=(self.status_queue,), )  # monitoring thread
        th.start()  # start monitoring thread
        for i in range(100):  # start doing our main function we would like to monitor
            print("{} {}".format(self.name, i))
            if i % 5 == 0:  # every 5 steps show status of progress
                self.status_queue.put(i)  # send status to Queue
                time.sleep(0.1)
        self.status_queue.put("STOP")  # stop Queue
        th.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # tests
    x = MyClass("Maria", Queue())
    x.my_run()
    print("*" * 200)
    x.my_run()
```

Comment: Wow - cool. I did not think about using queues for this.
What I meant was being able to monitor the progress from outside of the class. 
But you are correct - that's why I accepted your answer.

Comment: @user2549803 it is possible to monitor outside the class using the same primitive (Queue) but I did not see anybody who did it this way. Usually print statements inside class method are used if we consider console apps.